# Magento 2 - Extend onepage.phtml to add custom JS

Tags: checkout, javascript, custom

Magento 2

I have created a custom shipping method module and need to add custom JS to the checkout page where the shipping address and shipping method is set. But it is not working for me.

I have added my own `onepage.phtml` in the following location :

```
My_Module\view\frontend\templates\onepage.phtml
```

I also created a `checkout_index_index.xml` file in the following location :

```
My_Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml
```

The location of my JS :

```
My_Module\view\frontend\web\js\custom.js
```

The contents of my `onepage.phtml` file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        require(['jquery', 'custom-js'], function($) {
            alert('JS loaded');
        });
</script>
```

Contents of my `checkout_index_index.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.onepage">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">My_Module::onepage.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Contents of my `requirejs-config.js` file:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom-js: 'My_Module/js/custom-js'
        }
    }
};
```

Contents of my `module.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="My_Module" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
  </config>
```

When I add the contents of my `onepage.phtml` file to the core `onepage.phtml` file the JS is loaded correctly.

Also, when I change the `referenceBlock` `name` to `checkout.root` in the `checkout_index_index.xml` file, my JS files are loaded but it seems that only the `onepage.phtml` file is then rendered and nothing else... Am I using the wrong `name` value?

Is there a better way to include JS or am I just missing something? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran - no I did not create a theme, I only created a custom shipping method for which I need to have the custom JS on the checkout page

Comment: add sequence to your module.xml of Magento_Checkout

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran - how would I go about that? Sorry, Magento newbie here. :-) I already added a sequence in my `module.xml` file as I mentioned in the question. Do I need to change the way I did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You to try to create a custom component  and inject your custom component in checkout as described below.

**Step 1 )**

**File :** ***My_Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <!--Start custom Component-->
                                <item name="my-custom-component" xsi:type="array">                                          
                                         <item name="component" xsi:type="string">My_Module/js/custom</item>
                                </item>
                                <!--End Custom Component-->                                                            
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**step 2)**

**File** : ***My_Module\view\frontend\web\js\custom.js***

```
define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
], function (ko, $,Component) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        /* Set your custom component Ko Template here*/
         /* defaults: {
            template: 'My_Module/custom-component'
        },*/
        initialize: function () {
            alert("My Custom Component");
            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

**step 3)**

**Run below commands to remove static content and Cache files before testing**

```
sudo rm -rf var/pub/static/*
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf generated/*
```

Comment: Thank you! This led me in the right direction

Comment: In my custom checkout js file (My_Module\view\frontend\web\js\custom.js), I want to call the PHP function to set Magento session. How can I do that?

Comment: You may use jQuery Ajax and call a Controller to set Magento Session